# Replace a block of YAML

Tags: yaml, yq

I want to replace an array block in a yaml file with a specific different array.  I don't necessarily know how many elements are in the array to be replaced, nor what their values are.

yq seems like the best tool for the job (but I am open to other suggestions).

My yaml file looks kind of like this:

```
name: mything

parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    values:
      - storytest-DEV
      - storytest-PRD
  - name: destroy
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: validate
    type: boolean
    default: true

variables:
  - group: storytest
  - name: version
    value: "1.0.0"
```

and I want to replace the values of the parameters block with the name `environment` with a single element, lets say, foo.

so far I've got: `yq  '.parameters[] | select(.name == "environment").values = ["foo"]' infile.yml`

which gives me

```
name: environment
type: string
values:
  - foo
name: destroy
type: boolean
default: false
name: validate
type: boolean
default: true
```

which is what I want except that, I assume because of the `.parameters[] |`, I've lost the rest of my file (and the name fields no longer show dashes - meaning it's lost the fact that they're array elements, I assume

How can I replace the

```
- storytest-DEV
- storytest-PRD
```

with

```
- foo
```

and leave the rest of the file intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parentheses to retain the context outside the iteration:

```bash
(.parameters[] | select(.name == "environment")).values = ["foo"]
```

Or let `map` do the iteration, and update the array:

```bash
.parameters |= map(select(.name == "environment").values = ["foo"])
```

Both work with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), and [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq), resulting in:

```yaml
name: mything
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    values:
      - foo
  - name: destroy
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: validate
    type: boolean
    default: true
variables:
  - group: storytest
  - name: version
    value: "1.0.0"
```

Comment: Interesting!  So just an extra set of parens around what I had to retain the full context?  Thanks!

Comment: I found that 

yq 'setpath(["parameters",0,"values"]; ["foo"])' infile.yml 

seemed to work if I could rely on 'environment' being the first parameter (which I think I could in my use case, but it feels cleaner not to)

Comment: @timcrall You can also directly index into the array using `.parameters[0].values = ["foo"]` but your intention is easier to read and comprehend with a `select`.